# Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server, distribution-list

I am looking for a way to copy all the distribution lists from one of our users to a new user who is in a similar role.

All the scripts i've found so far are for on-prem AD.

I tried the below script and I got the bottom result when attempting to copy groups that are managed by Exchange Online.

```
#Parameters
$SourceUserAccount = "user1@test"
$TargetUserAccount = "user2@test"
 
#Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD
 
#Get the Source and Target users
$SourceUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$SourceUserAccount'"
$TargetUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$TargetUserAccount'"
 
#Check if source and Target users are valid
If($SourceUser -ne $Null -and $TargetUser -ne $Null)
{
    #Get All memberships of the Source user
    $SourceMemberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $SourceUser.ObjectId | Where-object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }
 
    #Get-AzureADUserOwnedObject -ObjectId $SourceUser.ObjectId
 
    #Loop through Each Group
    ForEach($Membership in $SourceMemberships)
    {
        #Check if the user is not part of the group
        $GroupMembers = (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Membership.Objectid).UserPrincipalName
        If ($GroupMembers -notcontains $TargetUserAccount)
        {
            #Add Target user to the Source User's group
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Membership.ObjectId -RefObjectId $TargetUser.ObjectId
            Write-host "Added user to Group:" $Membership.DisplayName
        }
    }
}
Else
{
    Write-host "Source or Target user is invalid!" -f Yellow
}
```

This is the error:

```
Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list.
RequestId: 887f93ae-590a-4c8a-b4ed-98d82357ef6a
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 23 Feb 2023 04:25:07 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:20 char:1
+ Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user2O ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureADGroupMember], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16. 
   PowerShell.AddGroupMember
```

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/qg6p2e/addazureadgroupmember_failing_for_mailenabled/. 
There are only a couple of results for this error for this function, consider checking https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Add-AzureADGroupMember%22+%22Cannot+Update+a+mail-enabled%22